# Why $E[f(x)]=\int p(x)f(x) dx$ and $E[f(x)]=\int xf(x) dx$ are same where they are expectancy of probability distributions?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value

I'm studying for statistics, and I realized two ways to represent expectancy of probability distribution that I gave above.

The problem is I don't understand how they can be same. One is x, which doesn't have to be between 1 and zero. But the other is p(x), which has to be between 1 and zero. How those two can give the same result?

Comment: what is $p(x)$?

Comment: How did you get $E[f(x)]=\int xf(x)dx$?

Comment: The second equaility mentioned in your title is not correct. Next to the first equality (correct if $p(x)$ denotes the density of $X$)  we also have the equality $\mathbb Ef(X)=\int f(X(\omega))P(d\omega)$ where the integral is taken on the original probability space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing notation so let me get the notation straight and it should clarify the definition of expectation. Also check wikipedia: [expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value), [Law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)

---

The definition of expectation $\mathbb{E}(X)$ for continuous random variable $X$ with density $p(x):\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is:

$$
\mathbb{E}(X):= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x p(x)dx. \tag{*}
$$

Now, suppose you have a new random variable $Y$ given by 
$$Y:= f(X), $$
for some function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. There is *the law of unconscious statistician* which says that the expectation of $Y$ is equal to
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y] \equiv \mathbb{E}[f(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) p(x)dx. 
$$
 This is a nice law, because it tells you, that you can forgo finding the density of $Y$ in order to compute its expectation directly according to $(*)$. Instead you can just "reuse" the density of $X$, while you substitute $x \Leftrightarrow f(x)$.

Comment: Hello, first thank you for your answer. I still have some questions. Lets say X is random variable that denotes result of a rolled dice. In this case is f(X) is defined(like we already know the value of f(X=1)) or we can define it as we like?

Comment: I didn't understand why we use function in this case. For example if E[X^2] is what we are actually calculating, we can just replace x^2 by another random variable E[Y]. Why we use function E[f(x)] instead?

Comment: I'm not sure what you ask about, can you be more specific? If you have $Y=X^2$ your function is $f(X)=X^2$ and you can apply the law of unconscious statistician using this function. I didnt prove why this law works, is this what you ask about: why this law works?